# Why I can't return reference of typedef'd type

Tags: c++, reference, return, typedef

Imagine this code:

```
class foo
{
    foo fff;
    int m_id;

    f & work() { return fff; }
};

typedef foo f;
```

This will compile fine, but this one:

```
class QX_SERVICE_DLL_EXPORT Code
{
public:
    Code() : m_Id(0) { ; }
    virtual ~Code() { ; }

    inline long id() const { return m_Id; }
    inline void setId(long id) { m_Id = id; }

    inline const QString & code() const { return m_Code; }
    inline void setCode(const QString & code) { m_Code = code; }

    inline const QString & name() const { return m_Name; }
    inline void setName(const QString & name) { m_Name = name; }

    inline const QSharedPointer<Code> & parent() const { return m_Parent; }
    inline void setParent(const QSharedPointer<Code> & parent) { m_Parent = parent; }

    CodeList & children() { return m_Children; }

private:
    long m_Id;
    QString m_Code;
    QString m_Name;
    QSharedPointer<Code> m_Parent;
    qx::QxCollection<long, QSharedPointer<Code>> m_Children;

    friend void registerOrm(qx::QxClass<Code> & t);
};

typedef qx::QxCollection<long, QSharedPointer<Code> > CodeList;
```

What's the difference? Why it doesn't work with class Code and works with class foo? 
Sorry for my broken English :)

I'm getting several errors, one of them is "Missing type specifier - int assumed" at `CodeList & children() { return m_Children; }`
I assume that typedef CodeList is not processed by the compiler when it is processing CodeList members in Code class, but I don't understand why it is working for the first case. If I write the following:

```
class Code;

typedef qx::QxCollection<long, QSharedPointer<Code>> CodeList;

class QX_SERVICE_DLL_EXPORT Code
{
...
```

Then everything works fine. 
BTW, I'm using MSVC 2010 compiler

Comment: Is `foo` `void`? Also: what's the type of `m_f`? Even more important: what error messages do you get?

Comment: Why don't you simply use public variables ?

Comment: @AlexandreC. because I want my classes to be encapsulated. A habit from C# maybe :-)

Comment: @Davita: you don't encapsulate anything by providing references to your internals. There is no point in a long string of getters and setters. To the very least, it provides no advantage over public members.

Comment: @AlexandreC. hmm. what if I don't return internals by reference..? sorry for the foolish question :)

Comment: @Davita: well, as a rough guideline, prefer to provide *few* methods which *perform actions*. Don't expose members unless you absolutely need to. If you do it, do it in the simplest way possible (and only provide setters if you really need to).

Comment: @Alexandre C getters and setters provide future compatibility may you ever change your class' internals.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is wrong:

```
typedef CodeList qx::QxCollection<long, QSharedPointer<Code> >;
```

You might mean:

```
typedef qx::QxCollection<long, QSharedPointer<Code> > CodeList;
```

I am pretty sure that the compiler should have provided an error message in that line of code, so my recommendation is *read the error messages*. If it hasn't, then you might not have included the header where the typedef is declared... *include it*. Additionally in the header where it is declared, you cannot use it *before* it has been declared (C++ process top to bottom, or kind of, in most cases at least...)

Comment: My bad, you are right, I fixed that but now CodeList is inaccessible from Code class. If I move typedef above class declaration, and use forward declaration for class Code, it compiles fine. Why does typedef  need to be declared above Code declaration? even this is not the case for the example I wrote (foo). Thanks

Comment: @Davita: You cannot use the typedef until it is actually defined. The compiler parses top-down, and it does not know what `CodeList` will mean. The comment about it being almost/kind of top-down is because there are exceptions. Types defined inside a class are available in the whole class definition (i.e. you can use it before it is defined if it is defined inside the class)

Comment: @Davita If you like having the new type name ordered before the old type then C++11 has a new syntax that allows it: `using CodeList = qx::QxCollection<long,QSharedPointer<Code>>;`. I do like this better than typedefs, and it can be templated.

Answer (score 2):

Put the `typedef` somewhere before the class definition and swap `qx::QxColl…etc` with `CodeList`:

```
typedef qx::QxCollection<long, QSharedPointer<Code> > CodeList;
class QX_SERVICE_DLL_EXPORT Code {
  ...
};
```